# Add migration to my class library ef core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a project with just one class library. I'm now trying to generate a migration in the class library.

Herer is my `DbContext`:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options) 
    { }

    public DbSet<Security> Services { get; set; }
    public DatabaseFacade DatabaseAccessor => this.Database;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Security>().HasNoKey();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I run the command

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project SecurityAttribute
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'DatabaseContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

My `IServiceCollections` looks like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddServiceAndRoleSecurity(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<ISecurityService, SecurityService>();
    services.AddMemoryCache();

    services.AddTransient<ISecurityRepository, SecurityRepository>();
    services.AddDbContext<IDatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
                 @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SecurityAttribute;Integrated Security=SSPI;",
                sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(10 * 60)
             ));
    services.AddTransient<IDatabaseContextFactory, DatabaseContextFactory>();
    return services;
}

public static IHost CreateDatabase(this IHost host)
{
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseContext>();
        var migrations = db.DatabaseAccessor.GetPendingMigrations();

        if (migrations.Any())
            db.DatabaseAccessor.Migrate();
    }
    return host;
}
```

My class library will be used as a nuget package. That's why I only have a class library.

Comment: @Clint: I don't have a main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution is to create a test project with Startup.cs. Where in configure services you register your `DbContext` and use this project for managing migrations.

To specify where migrations should be added you can add this option to `DbContext` options:

```cs
options.UseSqlServer(
    connectionString,
    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MyLib.Migrations"));
```

where `MyLib.Migrations` - name of the assembly where to store migrations

Comment: But the project should be used as a nuget without any startup?

Comment: You can create a simple app with Startup and Reference Your library. But publish to nuget just your library. A simple app will help you manipulate migration.

Comment: But I want a way to use migrations without creating an app for it.

Comment: You will save generated migrations to your library assembly and will be using them without app

Answer (score -1):

Are you running your command (dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project SecurityAttribute) in the package manager console? If so do you have the default project set correctly in the package manager console drop down? Is the start up project for the solution set to be the one with the Startup.cs?

Comment: Yes. I don't have any startup.cs in my class library.

Comment: It could be a comment at best. It is not an answer.