# Cant create initial EF Core migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I want to create my initial migration in EF-Core (Code First) with the command
`dotnet ef migrations add init`

I am getting the error

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' while attempting to activate 'ClubsLeague.Backend.Db.ClubContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

My class:

```
namespace ClubsLeague.Backend.Db
{
    public class ClubContext : DbContext
    {
        public ClubContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {            
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=ClubsLeague;User Id=sa;Password=Password!;");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to do it with verbose and s as arguments
or using `DbContextOptions<ClubContext>` in the constructor, both didnt work

Comment: How do you register the DB Context in your Program.cs file?

Comment: @gunr2171 its a class libary

Comment: I don't think you can make EF migrations directly on a class library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188984/add-migration-to-my-class-library-ef-core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: Had to do register the context in frontend...
that fixed it thanks for the hint

Comment: @DirkKirsche not sure that "it's a class library" answers gunr's question, btw - there's a difference between using a type in a referenced class library and registering the type with the dependency injector. Show us your `...AddDbContext" call in Program/Startup, where you do all your other AddTransient/AddScoped/AddSIngleton calls